# Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document' when created synchronous dynamic script tag

Tags: javascript, document.write

I wanted to include below script tag inside div dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.appnexus.com/ttj?id=12345678&cb=${CACHEBUSTER}"></script>
```

So I am able to do it by this way

```
document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.appnexus.com/ttj?id=12345678&cb=${CACHEBUSTER}">\x3C/script>')
```

But I am not able to include it when I create it like

```
window.onload = function() {
    var sNew = document.createElement("script");
    sNew.type = 'text/javascript';
    sNew.async = false;
    sNew.src = "http://ads.appnexus.com/ttj?id=12345678&cb=${CACHEBUSTER}";
    var s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(sNew, s0);
};
```

On Crome console it showing warning as

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

So what is wrong I done on above code. I wanted to include script Synchronously using `document.createElement("script")`

Comment: How are you loading the script that contains the above code? That seems to be what the error is about.

Comment: It placed inside `<body> <div> <script> //Here is the code </script> </div> </body>`

Comment: `src` of script includes `document.write()` so that's why it will not load asynchronously but I set up async as false still not getting desired result.